# Overflow-y scroll, child overflow

Tags: html, css

I have a div(parent) with width as 300px,height 100%, overflow-y: scroll. 
Inside the parent div, I have a child div which renders an angular component. Currently the component(child) is overflowing inside the parent. But I want it to be on top of everything.

Current working sample

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <title>Angular accoridon</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <style></style>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="controller">
    <div style="overflow-y: scroll;width: 300px;height: 500px">
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>
        <input type="text" ng-model="searchTerm" />
        <div ng-if="searchTerm" style="width: 500px;">
          <div
            ng-click="onClick(item)"
            ng-repeat="item in items | filter: searchTerm"
            style="background: lightgray; padding: 20px;margin: 5px 0px;"
          >
            {{ item.name }}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/3.0.2/normalize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
    </div>
    <script>
      angular.module('app', []).controller('controller', function($scope) {
        $scope.searchTerm = '';
        $scope.items = [
          {name: 'First'},
          {name: 'Second'},
          {name: 'Third'},
          {name: 'Fourth'},
          {name: 'Fifth'},
          {name: 'Sixth'},
          {name: 'Seventh'},
          {name: 'Eighth'},
          {name: 'Ninth'},
          {name: 'Tenth'},
          {name: 'Eleventh'},
          {name: 'Twelth'},
          {name: 'Thirteenth'},
          {name: 'Fourteenth'},
          {name: 'Fifteenth'},
        ];
        $scope.onClick = function(item) {
          console.log(item.name);
          $scope.searchTerm = '';
        };
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Required:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <title>Angular accoridon</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <style></style>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="controller">
    <div style="overflow-y: scroll;width: 300px;height: 500px">
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>
        <input type="text" ng-model="searchTerm" />
        <div ng-if="searchTerm" style="width: 500px;position: fixed">
          <div
            ng-click="onClick(item)"
            ng-repeat="item in items | filter: searchTerm"
            style="background: lightgray; padding: 20px;margin: 5px 0px;"
          >
            {{ item.name }}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
    </div>
    <script>
      angular.module('app', []).controller('controller', function($scope) {
        $scope.searchTerm = '';
        $scope.items = [
          {name: 'First'},
          {name: 'Second'},
          {name: 'Third'},
          {name: 'Fourth'},
          {name: 'Fifth'},
          {name: 'Sixth'},
          {name: 'Seventh'},
          {name: 'Eighth'},
          {name: 'Ninth'},
          {name: 'Tenth'},
          {name: 'Eleventh'},
          {name: 'Twelth'},
          {name: 'Thirteenth'},
          {name: 'Fourteenth'},
          {name: 'Fifteenth'},
        ];
        $scope.onClick = function(item) {
          console.log(item.name);
          $scope.searchTerm = '';
        };
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am able to get it working it position: fixed, the result is coming on the top, but if I start scrolling the parent, then the results stay wherever they are(as they are fixed) and do not stay stick to the input.
The expected behaviour is that they should stick to the input text box on scroll of parent as well as the results must be on the top.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This should be easily done for your problem and would help a lot to understand, but also to resolve it.

Comment: In the textarea where you wrote your question, there is an icon to the right of the image icon. This will allow you to write down your code so we can see it and also facilitate helping you out.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS positioning to get the element placement right. Look at the following link to understand your options https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp.

In the modified snippet below, First textbox appears inside the top of your div with position:fixed. This will stay where it is even with the page scroll.

However, the second texbox, which is at the bottom has position absolute, it will be absolute relative to your parent container, which is your parent div.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <title>Angular accoridon</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <style></style>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="controller">
    <div style="overflow-y: scroll;width: 300px;height: 500px">
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div style="position:absolute; bottom:0">
        <input type="text" ng-model="searchTerm" />
        <div ng-if="searchTerm" style="width: 500px;position: fixed">
          <div
            ng-click="onClick(item)"
            ng-repeat="item in items | filter: searchTerm"
            style="background: lightgray; padding: 20px;margin: 5px 0px;"
          >
            {{ item.name }}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div style="position:fixed; top:0">
        <input type="text" ng-model="searchTerm" />
        <div ng-if="searchTerm" style="width: 500px;position: fixed">
          <div
            ng-click="onClick(item)"
            ng-repeat="item in items | filter: searchTerm"
            style="background: lightgray; padding: 20px;margin: 5px 0px;"
          >
            {{ item.name }}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
      <div>Hello World!!</div>
    </div>
    <script>
      angular.module('app', []).controller('controller', function($scope) {
        $scope.searchTerm = '';
        $scope.items = [
          {name: 'First'},
          {name: 'Second'},
          {name: 'Third'},
          {name: 'Fourth'},
          {name: 'Fifth'},
          {name: 'Sixth'},
          {name: 'Seventh'},
          {name: 'Eighth'},
          {name: 'Ninth'},
          {name: 'Tenth'},
          {name: 'Eleventh'},
          {name: 'Twelth'},
          {name: 'Thirteenth'},
          {name: 'Fourteenth'},
          {name: 'Fifteenth'},
        ];
        $scope.onClick = function(item) {
          console.log(item.name);
          $scope.searchTerm = '';
        };
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```